# swift ? must be followed by a call, member lookup, or subscript

Tags: swift

I think I'm looking at some outdated code:

```
@IBAction func stockLevelDidChange(sender: AnyObject) {
        if var currentCell = sender as? UIView {
            while (true) {
                currentCell = currentCell.superview!;
                if let cell = currentCell as? ProductTableCell {
                    if let id = cell.productId? {
                        var newStockLevel:Int?;
                        if let stepper = sender as? UIStepper {
                            newStockLevel = Int(stepper.value);
                        }
                        else if let textfield = sender as? UITextField {
                            if let newValue = textfield.text.toInt()? {
                                newStockLevel = newValue;
                            }
                        }
                        if let level = newStockLevel {
                            products[id].4 = level;
                            cell.stockStepper.value = Double(level);
                            cell.stockField.text = String(level);
                        }
                    }
                break;
                }
            }
            displayStockTotal();
        }
    }
```

But in the first line of the function I get " '?' must be followed by a call, member lookup, or subscript" (for the question mark after `as`)

What does this error mean and how does this code change for Swift 1.2?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Actually the `as?` are all fine. The problem is this line:

```
if let id = cell.productId?
```

Just remove the question mark at the end of that. It makes no sense.

Comment: This worked. But why does Xcode show that the error is on the `if var currentCell = sender as? UIView` line?

Answer (score 1):

In 1.2, `toInt` is gone. So,

```
if let newValue = textfield.text.toInt()?
```

Should be replaced with:

```
if let newValue:Int? = Int(textField.text!)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `if let newValue = textfield.text.toInt()? {` .. If `toInt()` returns an `Int?` then just get rid of the `?` there.

Comment: Interesting this is only an error in Swift 1.2. In Swift 1.1 this actually compiles and works.

Comment: what's the language reason behind this? I have the same error for ```if (self.cat? != nil) { return self }```